# How to merge vertices / faces on a mesh without altering texture

Tags: texturing, vertices, faces

I'm working on a mesh I got from photogrammetry and I need to clean it up a bit as it has around 2 million faces.

What I'm trying to do here is to merge faces that are on the same axis (merge faces that represent the roof or walls for example).

I've managed to merge a few by selecting faces and pressing the "F" key but sometimes I get some texture alterations (as show on image).

How can I avoid getting this alteration?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can as you completely change the UV map as soon as you merge the face

Comment: You will have to merge the vertices before texturing and UV editing because adding or removing faces changes the UV map and if you are merging them you will have to UV edit them later

Comment: To achieve what you want, you should be merging verts on a copy of your original, UV map your copy after completing the geometry, and then bake a texture from your original to your copy.